# How do I generate vectors from a CSR matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, keras

I'm attempting to train a neural network on bag-of-words features which are represented by a CSR matrix. Because my dataset is ~100k instances with a ~100k length vocabulary, I cannot fit all vectors into memory.

```
for trainIndices, testIndices in indices.split(X):
    print("\tAnalyzing fold {}...".format(fold))
    print("\t\tIsolating training data...")
    train_X = countVectorizer.fit_transform( X[trainIndices].apply( lambda x:
                                                                    ' '.join(x)
                                                                    )
                                             )
    train_y = y[trainIndices]

    print("\t\tIsolating test data...")
    test_X = countVectorizer.transform( X[testIndices].apply( lambda x:
                                                              ' '.join(x)
                                                              )
                                        )
    test_y = y[testIndices]

    cnn = build(countVectorizer.vocabulary_.__len__())

    print("\t\tFitting training data...")

    print(type(train_X))
    generator=createGenerator(train_X, train_y)

    # implement a generator for this.
    cnn.fit_generator( generator       = generator,
                       steps_per_epoch = 10000,
                       validation_data = ( test_X, test_y )
                       )
```

Thus I am using Keras' **`fit_generator()`** method, which if I understand correctly, feeds gradual data to training. I am not dealing with images, so I tried creating my own generator method to yield values. However, I am unsure how to provide instances from the CSR matrix through iteration/yield.

```
def createGenerator(x,y):
    for index_X, index_y in zip(x, y):
        # print(x,y)
        yield(x, y)
```

So far, I've tried converting to coo matrices:

```
def createGenerator(x,y):
    cx = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(x)
    cy = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(y)
    print(cx)
    print(cy)
    for a,b in zip(cx.row, cy.row):
        yield(a,b)
```

I've also tried iterating over the CSR directly, which resulted in ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. I'm not exactly sure how to generate vectors that the neural network will accept from the CSR matrix. I may also be completely on the wrong track by using a custom generator.

Comment: When you iterate on a `csr` matrix, you get single row `csr` matrices.  If `fit_generator` can't take the multirow matrix, it can't take a single row one either.  Look at the result of your generator.  Don't guess as to what it produces.